# 12 requests are being fired to the server instead of once every 5 seconds in the AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am sending a simple JSON String as `{"tesla": "48.846305"}` every 5 seconds  to the server but I noticed many requests `12` are being fired to the server in one second but I want to send the data just once every 5 seconds. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Output:**

```
06-14 12:01:29.643: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:29.824: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:29.834: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:29.984: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:29.984: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.134: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.144: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.284: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.284: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.454: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.454: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.604: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.604: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.755: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.755: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:30.895: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:30.905: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.91065752874712}
06-14 12:01:31.085: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.085: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:31.225: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.225: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:31.365: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.365: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:31.525: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.525: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:31.705: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.705: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:31.856: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
06-14 12:01:31.856: I/System.out(7915): The output of : doInBackground {"tesla":23.776338448540205}
06-14 12:01:32.046: I/System.out(7915): The output of the StringBulder: {"status":280}
```

**Code:**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                float magX = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float magY = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float magZ = sensorEvent.values[2];

                magneticX.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
                magneticY.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
                magneticZ.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));

                double teslaXYZ = (Math.sqrt((magX * magX) + (magY * magY)
                        + (magZ * magZ)));
                magneticT.setText(Double.toString(teslaXYZ));

                try {
                    JSONObject tesla = new JSONObject();
                    tesla.put("tesla", teslaXYZ);
                    telsaString = tesla.toString();

                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(telsaString);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground "
                        + params[0]);

                URL myUrl = new URL(
                        "https://serverside-rhcloud.com/webapi/tesla");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.connect();



                // create data output stream
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                // write to the output stream from the string
                wr.writeBytes(params[0]);

                wr.close();
//              System.out.println("The output of getResponsecode: "
//              + conn.getResponseCode());


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                // System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder before "
                // + routes);
                System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder: "
                        + sb.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(telsaString);
                }
            }, 5 * 1000);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are invoking your `AsyncTask` *on every sensor reading*. In most cases, you are going to get sensor readings much more frequently than once every five seconds.

Second, you are *also* invoking your `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute()`, by generating a memory-leaking `Handler` and using `postDelayed()`. This just adds to your pile of tasks.

Third, you have no means of stopping any of this. This code will execute until your process terminates. Doing network I/O every five seconds indefinitely is unlikely to make users happy.

Fourth, you do not have adequate thread safety surrounding `telsaString`, which is being used by multiple threads, occasionally simultaneously.

---

Let's ignore the issue of whether doing network I/O every five seconds is likely to cause users to attempt to murder you, and focus on the rest.

If you want to do a bit of work every five seconds on a background thread, from an already-running process, use `ScheduledExecutorService`. You don't have to fuss with a `Handler`, you don't have to fuss with `AsyncTask`.

Have your `SensorEventListener` cache your last sensor readings. Have it kick off the `ScheduledExecutorService` *only if it is not already running*, not on every reading. Use `synchronized` or other Java thread safety mechanisms to ensure that either the `SensorEventListener` is updating the readings *or* the `ScheduledExecutorService` is consuming the readings at any one moment, not both simultaneously.

When it comes time to cease this work, you can `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` the `ScheduledExecutorService`, after first unregistering your `SensorEventListener`.